# SVG SMIL animation workarounds for Safari?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm experiencing issues with a basic SVG animation in Safari.

It fails elegantly by just displaying the SVG without animation, but if possible I'd like to have it work in Safari as well.

The animation is very similar to an example found [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-animation.html):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <rect x="10" y="10" height="110" width="110"
         style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff">

        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="20s"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 60 60"
            to="360 60 60"
            repeatCount="indefinite" 
        />
    </rect>

</svg>
```

Preferably something native, but if a library is necessary that's okay too.

Comment: It is working for me on desktop Safari 7.05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a transform attribute specified on your rect element, so Safari is throwing up its hands.

Change your rect to:

```
 <rect x="10" y="10" height="110" width="110"
         style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff" transform="rotate(0 60 60)">
```

and all is well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but specifying the transform doesn't seem to fix it. In Chrome it still rotates as it should, however Safari doesn't like it and just displays a static square.

Comment: Works in iOS Safari 7 for me. I don't have a mac desktop.

Comment: Thank you both for testing. I'll accept this answer. I'm testing out of Windows and the highest version of Safari I've been able to install is 5.1.7.